# French tourist visa multiple countries

Tags: visas, schengen, europe, france, schengen-visas

I applied for a short stay visa at the french embassy. The plan was to stay in France for the whole, and I have applied with only France as the destination.

Now we are thinking of visiting other countries in the Schengen area. And I have found this in their FAQ

[Unless stated differently on the visa stamp, short-stay visas are valid for all the 26 States in the Schengen area](https://france-visas.gouv.fr/en_US/web/france-visas/faq)

And I have also found this [stock image](https://www.dreamstime.com/french-european-schengen-visa-stamp-passport-immigration-stamps-close-up-image108609766) stating that entry is allowed for "FRANCE (+1 TRANSIT SCHENGEN)"

Does this mean that I will get a visa for France only? And if so what are the possibilities of visting other schengen contries on such visa.

Comment: The stock image is not relevant to you because it is a type-D visa.  Type D denotes long-stay visas.  Short-stay visas are type C.

Comment: The stock image _also_ seems to be from before the rules were changed so type D visa holders could make short visits to other Schengen countries without further visas.

Comment: Do you have the medical insurance, required funds and the way back ticket for the whole travel time in Schengen area?

Comment: @gstorto Yes and it's documented with the application.

Comment: @YasserA You can freely travel on the Schengen zone, supposing these three conditions are valid and you do not exceed the 90-day stay limit.